# Qt ui for an OS

Tags: c++, qt

Am i able to create an OS's User Interface with Qt's .ui file?(Qt .ui file is an xml file)
This confused me long time already,bcuz in http://qt.io

you can see

BUILT WITH Qt
LG’s webOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes and Qt is a cross-platform application development framework. Some of the well known applications developed with Qt are KDE, Opera, Google Earth, and Skype. Qt was first publicly released on May 1995. It is dual licensed. That means, it can be used for creating open source applications as well as commercial ones. Qt toolkit is a very powerful toolkit.